# SQL WHERE clause: Get all rows / only matching rows based on value

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am do this in VB.NET for SQL Server but I think it is a general SQL question.

I am building an SQL query and I want to avoid doing this:

```
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Table"
If Not IsDbNull(Value) Then
    SQL &= " WHERE Value = " & Value
End If
```

Is there a way to to write a WHERE clause so that if a value is NULL, then return all rows in the query otherwise only return rows that match the value supplied.

For instance:

If the value is NULL then the result set would be:

```
ID  Value  City 
1   1      New York 
2   1      London
3   2      Paris
4   4      Mumbai
```

If the value is 2 then the result set would be:

```
ID  Value  City 
3   2      Paris
```

I could write two separate queries or write the query as I have above, but I want to know if there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using parameters queries.  One method is:

```
WHERE Value = ? OR ? IS NULL
```

I should note that the resulting query probably will not use an index.  So, two separate queries is probably better from a performance perspective.

Comment: I agree about the parameters and the example is simplified to save space.

Comment: OMG... I have been writing SQL since the mid 80s and I cannot believe I missed an answer that simple. Thanks Gordon.